# keyup is not firing

Tags: jquery, keyup

I had this working but it has stopped. The weird thing is that 'mouseup' works but 'keyup' does not.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
 $('#chordprodiv').on('keyup mouseup', 'textarea', function () {
    chordpro_toCHORDSHEET();
});
```

});

Here is 2 fixes after the comments. I updated jquery and changed the function to .on, and I corrected the event format so they are in the same string. The code was already in the document.ready but I added that for clarity.

I have since targeted the parent div and identified the 'textarea' selector as per another suggestion.

Also here's the html

```
 <textarea id="chordpro" name="chordpro"></textarea>
```

Comment: `.live` is so old - what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: I'm using 1.8.3, that's weird. I'll check the sources.

Comment: Okay, got that fixed. It's 3.1.1 now. It didn't like .live so I changed it to .on. Now neither of the events are firing.

Comment: Try placing your code inside document.ready function.

Comment: It's always been inside the document.ready. It's actually the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.live is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery, you should be using .on

Additionally your events should be together in one string...

```
$('#chordpro').on('keyup mouseup', function () {
    chordpro_toCHORDSHEET();
});
```

The event handler should be called in the format, as shown below.
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );

Comment: Okay, straightened out the event handler.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#chordpro').on('keyup mouseup', function () {
        chordpro_toCHORDSHEET();
    });

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you set the event handler.  Jquery .on() has this overload that you are using:

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

but from the documentation (found at http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Meaning you have two options.

**1.** use the other overload of .on

```
$('#chordpro').on('keyup mouseup', function () {
...
```

or

**2.** put the event handler on a parent element

HTML:

```
<div id="chordpro-div">
  <textarea id="chordpro" name="chordpro"></textarea>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#chordpro-div').on('keyup mouseup', 'textarea', function () {
...
```

Comment: I targeted the parent div as you suggested but that did not correct the issue. I did add the code to the dialog page itself and it fires when it is on the page. But then it doesn't recognize any of the javascript that is loaded on the parent page.

Comment: Not sure what the issue with your targeting parent div, here is a codepen illustrating it working:  http://codepen.io/jolyeons/pen/kkzrqA . Also not sure what you mean by dialog page/parent page, possibly the other code in your project is requiring a different solution,

Hopefully you get this working, glad to try to help more if I can